# PayPal payment_status not sent at all

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to check the payment Status over IPN of PayPal and there is a problem. I'm using [this](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/)

and I have some checks for Fraud one on which is:

```
if ( $_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed' ) {
        // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
        $errmsg .= "Payment not completed! But ".$_POST['payment_status']."\n";
}
```

The problem is that **payment_status** isn't sent and the Payment is not processed in my code.
Also I found the same issue with **mc_amount3** and **mc_gross**. One time PayPal send **mc_amount3** and one time **mc_gross**. I couldn't find information in the web or on the Search or in the PayPal.

I'm really confused.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this, I am not getting it at all either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [IPN Variables reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/):

mc_amount3: Amount of payment for regular subscription period, regardless of currency.
mc_gross: Full amount of the customer's payment, before transaction fee is subtracted. Equivalent to payment_gross for USD payments. If this amount is negative, it signifies a refund or reversal, and either of those payment statuses can be for the full or partial amount of the original transaction.

As far as the payment_status not being included, that is a variable that should be passed. It is possible that the payment_status is coming back as 'Pending' or 'Processed' instead, causing the script to fail. Try writing out to an error log what the payment_status is.

Comment: I'm sending the data to my Email and it fails like this:
`IPN failed fraud checks: 
Payment not completed! But (white space)`
And I have included it in like this:
`$msg = "... But ".$_POST['payment_status']`
And with `mc_amount3` and `mc_gross` is the same, first time one is sent second time the other...